# android ANR(activity not responding) trace.txt

Tags: android, trace, android-anr-dialog

I have in my app an occasional and very hard to reproduce ANR event. Today it's happened, and I pulled out from the device the file trace.txt situated in /data/anr.
Unfortunately I can't understand the data in this file, here is the complete file content.
Can someone understand what is keeping my app's UI unresponsive?
I've already read similar questions but still can't read the file..

I've pasted the complete trace.txt file content to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/f8ZYTXUX)

EDIT

the file on pastebin is not available anymore and I do not have access to the trace.txt file anymore, so the answer can be closed.

thank you

Comment: trace.txt is the situation of all running threads when the ANR occurred. And ANRs occur when you perform long activities in the Main thread. Search for your threads in the Text file and see which Thread was executing when ANR happened. OR, check what you are doing in the Main thread that is taking long time and offload it to Threads.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Strictmode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) to find out what calls delay a specific thread. The best way to use it is in the following form. In your application onCreate() you enable StrictMode. After that, (almost) all slow calls on that thread will be reported to your Log, with a full stacktrace of where it happened.

In your custom Application class:

```
 public void onCreate() {
     if (DEVELOPER_MODE) {
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectAll()    // detect everything potentially suspect
                 .penaltyLog()   // penalty is to write to log
                 .build());
         StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectAll()
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .build());
     }
     super.onCreate();
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Mohamed_AbdAllah has written on his comment "trace.txt is the situation of all running threads when the ANR occurred." Finding the reason of ANR from a thread while ANR occured seems impossible with a trace like you post. If you want to understand what those texts in trace mean, you may be interested in [this](http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-read-dalvik-sigquit-output.html). (You can get which thread is long running when the ANR occured from trace but this probably does not help you)

Alternatively, if you want to see what type of crashes/ANRs do you have with your andoid application(I assume that you are interested in applications that you developped and published on google play) you can use a crash report api. I use [crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/) for this purpose and it really helps me to fix my applications crashes. When you add this api to you application you can trace all Crashes/ANRs on a web page.

If your aim is understanding how to find reasons of ANRs from trace.txt then I have no idea. But if you need to find and fix your crashes/ANRs, then use a crash report api.

Edit: I assumed you are talking about an application which you've developed and published on google play. If you are talking about an application which is not published to google play yet, @Jeffrey Klardie's suggestion is just what you need. But it is not advised to enable [Strictmode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) on applications at google play.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is the compiler is waiting for some interweb operation on the UI thread.

Comment: can you explain better please? what do you mean for "waiting for some interweb operation"?

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to help on this without code to see what's going on, so instead I'll list what I would do to my own code should I be in this situation.

1. Run a Static Analysis tool on my code to identify some odd behavior (infinite loops, missing cases, etc.). Personally I use [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/).

   1. Review the errors that pop-up from the Static Analysis tool, correct the ones that make sense for what you are doing.
2. Look through the code for any occurrences of "evil" code such as really long loops, synchronous activity that can be asynchronous, use of the `sleep()` function, asynchronous activity that is being treated synchronously, etc.
3. If none of the above made an impact start throwing in `Log` statements all over the place. Watch the output from a run and see where it gets to or what is repeating.
4. If none of the above worked, pop open a beer do a little yoga and then get back on the prowl and dig some more!